# Where is this budha from and would love to know any history of maker?

Tags: history

[image]
Any information I would be grateful for. I have no idea be am very curious about this any a few other items I purchased recently.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this could be Jigme Lingpa, who's is often depicted with this typical shape of eyebrows and this style of facial hair. But on a second look, I'm pretty sure this is obviously [Padmasambhava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padmasambhava) or Guru Rinpoche, the founder of Tibetan Buddhism himself, thanks to the unmistakable hat, the dress with epaulets, as well as the ritual objects he holds.

According to a [traditional iconographic description](https://www.himalayanart.org/search/set.cfm?setID=3408),

> ...he is white in colour with a reddish hue, one face adorned with a moustache and goatee, the right hand holds to the heart an upright gold vajra. The left hand placed in the lap holds a white skullcup filled with nectar, jewels and a long-life vase. The ornate katvanga staff of a Vajrayana mendicant decorated with streamers rests against the left shoulder. Adorned with gold earrings and necklaces, the head is covered with a lotus hat, a gift of the King of Zahor, of silk brocade topped with a half-vajra and a single vulture feather. Attired in various robes of different colours reflecting the disciplines of the Vinaya, Bodhisattva and Mantra Vehicles, he sits atop a sun and moon disc above a lotus blossom rising from the blue waters of Dhanakosha lake.

You can see the ring for the [staff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kha%E1%B9%ADv%C4%81%E1%B9%85ga) on your copy, while the staff itself seems to have been lost.

[image: Padmasambhava statue]

> Here, Padmasambhava can be seen in his most well known representation. His eyes are open in a piercing gaze; his face is wrathful and smiling, blazing magnificently with mysterious power. He cradles a khatvanga in his left arm, representing his consort Mandarava, who arouses realization of emptiness. His khatvanga is crowned with three severed heads and a trident, symbolizing Padmasambhava's liberation from the three kayas of desire, form and formlessness.
>
> He wears a lotus hat ornamented with a sun and moon, representing skillful means and wisdom. His hat also has a vajra top, symbolizing his unshakable samadhi, and is crowned with a vulture feather, representing his realization of the highest view. In his right hand he holds a vajra, an implement used in Tantric ritual to symbolize the union of conventional and ultimate truth. His left hand rests in his lap in the gesture of meditation (Dhyana Mudra) and holds a skull cup containing the vase of immortality. The vase is filled with the nectar of deathless wisdom and is adorned with leaves of a sacred flowering tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this information. I am very grateful for your wisdom on this subject. 